# refactoring generated action code in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I generate a scaffold I get the standard actions index, new, show, create .... all of which contain a line e.g. like

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

Does it make sense to put this line in a seperate method into the controller like

```
def load
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

Is this an advantage? Thx for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to the separate method, and also yes to using a before_filter.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # Whitelist your before_filter like this. Or you can blacklist it with :except => []
  before_filter :load_comment, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :show]

  def show
  end

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all 
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # etc ...

  protected

  def load_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: hey thx for your reply. why has it to be protected? and what if I have already a different query like '@comment = Comment.new' in my action. Does before_filter override it? Do I put the method before my action methods or at the end of my controller?

Comment: See my edit for how to whitelist your filter, which I should have included in the first place. As for why it is protected. If it was public, and you had the right catch-all route in place then `load_comment` would be callable as a regular controller action. It's just a precaution.